# Multiline regex powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I would be grateful to receive some solution for my problem  connected with parsing/ regex html file code:

d:\acc.html

```
<!-- WebSite-Watcher Demo Report -->



<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>WebSite-Watcher Report</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
a:link, a:active {
    color: #4040A0;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:visited {
    color: #8080A0;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover {
    background: #FFF000;
    color: #FF0000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
body, td {
   font-size: 11px;
   line-height: 15px;
   font-family: Verdana, Arial;
}
li {
   list-style: square;
   font-size: 11px;
   line-height: 15px;
   margin-top: 10px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<center>

<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0" width="80%">
<tr>
<td>
<font color="#336699" style="font-size: 18px;"><b>Highlighted changes</b></font><br>
<div style="border-top: 1px dashed dadada; margin-top: 5px;"></div>
<br>

<font color="#f00000">This report displays the first 200 characters of highlighted changes,<br>
the length can be changed individually with the <b>wsw_url_highlighted_changes(200)</b> variable.</font><br>
<br>




<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td style="border-bottom-color: #d0d0d0; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; background-color: #eaeaea;"><!-- F1E896 -->
<font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Lorem ipsum</b></font><br><font color="#808080"> | <a href="http://www.hjccx.com/" target="_top">Web page</a> | <a href="file://x:/wswdb/wswdatabase_wsw/0004/2015052915594644815599.htm_chg.htm#wswchange1" target="_top">Local page</a></font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border-bottom-color: #f0f0f0; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; background-color: #f8f8f8;"><!-- F5F2C7 -->
<blockquote>
<br>
</blockquote>
</td>
</tr>
</table><br>
<br>


<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td style="border-bottom-color: #d0d0d0; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; background-color: #eaeaea;"><!-- F1E896 -->
<font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Lorem ipsum</b></font><br><font color="#808080">18-06-2015 | <a href="http://www.no target="_top">Web page</a> | <a href="file://x:/wswdb/wswdatabase_wsw/0004/2015052915594536915585.htm_chg.htm#wswchange1" target="_top">Local page</a></font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border-bottom-color: #f0f0f0; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; background-color: #f8f8f8;"><!-- F5F2C7 -->
<blockquote>
Lorem ipsum BBBBBBBBBBBB<br>
</blockquote>
</td>
</tr>
</table><br>
<br>

<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td style="border-bottom-color: #d0d0d0; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; background-color: #eaeaea;"><!-- F1E896 -->
<font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Lorem ipsum</b></font><br><font color="#808080">18-06-2015 | <a href="http://www.no target="_top">Web page</a> | <a href="file://x:/wswdb/wswdatabase_wsw/0004/2015052915594536915585.htm_chg.htm#wswchange1" target="_top">Local page</a></font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border-bottom-color: #f0f0f0; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; background-color: #f8f8f8;"><!-- F5F2C7 -->
<blockquote>
Lorem ipsum BBBBBBBBBBBB<br>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAaa AA<br>
</blockquote>
</td>
</tr>
</table><br>
<br>


<br>
<br>

<div style="border-top: 1px dashed dadada;"></div>
<font color="#808080"><i>Report date: 18-06-2015</i></font><br>
</td>
</tr>
</table><br>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to 'clean' this file from empty entries like the first one(no text just some empty spaces or usually just 
.

I know that in powershell there is solution for multi regex and it will probably look like:

d:\pattern.txt

```
(?=<table cellpadding="5" ).*(?=<blockquote>).{0,6}(?=<\/blockquote>)
```

script:(thanks Jisaak)

```
$content = (Get-Content 'd:\acc.txt' -raw) 
$pattern = (Get-Content 'd:\pattern.txt' -raw)

[regex]::Replace($content, $pattern, '',`
     [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline `
     -bor [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Singleline)
```

I mean- from  (0-6 of any symbols) )

This regex doesn't work i have problems with properly writing this advanced regex. Thanks for any help

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to "clean", could supply a minimal example with a sample input and output?

Comment: @ShellFish I am sorry, just corrected it.

Comment: You should still be more descriptive about the condition for removing a table, I cannot figure out why one table is removed and the other has not.

Comment: the report is generated by other software to generate changes in website. I have to delete the entries that doesnt contain useful text only <br>, spaces, single letters etc. thats why i selected max 6 letters

Comment: @ShellFish I think the table that gets removed has `<blockquote><br></blockquote>` and the ones which are kept have `<blockquote>lorem ipsum...</blockquote>`.

Comment: its one of my first uses of powershell, previously i wrote some simple stuff in windows prompt, but i couldn't find any information about multiline regex in windows prompt.  The binary OR is the result of combining my own code by modifing others, it would give the same result without    -bor [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Singleline) ?

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for clearing that up. Try to create a regex which matches a starting table, followed with content up until a block quote, then check for occurrences of `<>[ \t\.]*<>*` until the closing quote.

Comment: i did not understand this advice, sorry

Comment: @jawjaw do you have to use Regex? I bet you could read in the data and force it into an HTML or XML object type, which might let you loop through the nodes for empty ones to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Would this problem be easier if you didn't have to deal with multiple lines?

My experience with regex is limited and html is non-existant, but the below workaround can turn your blocks into single lines (and back to blocks again)

```
$file  = (Get-Content ".\acc.html" -raw)

# Replace new line CR LF with a string (e.g. NEWLINE)
$file2 = ([regex]::Replace($file, ">`r`n", ">NEWLINE", "Singleline"))
$file2 | out-file ".\acc_edited.html"

# Single line regex replacement here to get rid of empty table.
# String NEWLINE can be used to indicate a new line.

# Replace the string with new line characters CR LF after regex replacement.
[regex]::Replace($file2, ">NEWLINE", ">`r`n", "Singleline") | Out-File ".\acc_original.html"
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
(?<=<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">).*
(?=<blockquote>)|(?<=<blockquote>).{0,6}(?=<\/blockquote>)
```

Comment: it deleted everything , just one piece left. i mean one good left also if i change 0,6 to 0,2  almost everything is deleted.